# Embed tag length issues

Tags: html, embed

I have a pdf in my media library that I am trying to embed on a page. The width works fine but the length does not. I am trying to basically represent 8.5 x 11 on the screen. As it is only about 3-4 inches in screen length are shown and the rest is scroll bar.

```
<embed src='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/.../somefile.pdf' width='1000px' length='1200px' />
```

I have even tried using length='100%'.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out. embed tags do not work with pdf's because it does not render through the browser. Using the object tag worked:

```
<object data='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/...somefile.pdf' type="application/pdf" 

width="1000px" height="1200px">

<p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. You can download the pdf
<a href='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/.../somefile.pdf'>here</a>
</p>

</object>
```